# APK path is not specified when trying to run app using IntellIJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, dalvik

I am learning to create Android apps. My device is a Galaxy Note 3. When I run the app I get the error APK path is not specified. I have tried

- Restarting the IDE and running as admin.
- Tried messing with Project Structure.
- Created a new project. Did not change any settings from defaults.
- Tried creating various directories in the project directory.
- Tried the instructions [here](http://jfseandroid.blogspot.ca/2013/06/troubleshooting-android-developer-studio.html) that would push the app using a APK. Only thing now is that I need to figure out how to create a APK before running (obviously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying for 6 hours and noticing using Eclipse was working fine. I renamed the .IntelliJIdea12 to generate a new profile. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. The error occurs because of apk path mismatch. Configuring the apk path as below should get it working.

In your module's .iml file specify the APK_PATH option:

```
<option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/YourAppName-debug-unaligned.apk" />
```

*Note: Your apk might not be located at /build/apk/. You can physically locate the apk by navigating through your app location and mention the path to that directory here.*

Now rebuild your project. It should build and work as expected.

Comment: I think I tried that when I had the issue. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I think it depends on the version of IDE also.